# Convert a JSON string to a JSON object (Not java script Object)

Tags: jquery, json

I need to convert a string into a JSON object so that I can post it using AJAX. As of now, all the answers I could find were converting it to javascript objects due to which there were no double quotes on the 'keys' and had double quotes only on the values. 
I have searched a lot, but almost all the answers convert it to a JS object, and the REST endpoint will only accept JSON object. Please help.

I have a string in this format:

{"subject":"school,","description":"top10,","classsize":"35"}

Function to get form data as JSON string

```
function getFormData($form){
     var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
     var indexed_array = {};

     $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
      indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
                    });

                    return indexed_array;
                }
```

and then I use JSON.stringify on the form data.

Comment: `{"subject":"school,","description":"top10,","classsize":"35"}` _is_ valid JSON.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()`:

```js
var string = "'{\"subject\":\"school,\",\"description\":\"top10,\",\"classsize\":\"35\"}'";
//remove the backslashes
var string_ed = unescape(string);
//remove the surrounding single quotes
string_ed = string_ed.substr(1, string_ed.length - 2);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(string_ed);

document.getElementById("result").innerText = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your answer and the snippet works just fine, However it does not work in my case. So  as I mentioned the function which I am using to get the form data, I get the form data as :  `"'{\"subject\":\"school,\",\"description\":\"top10,\",\"classsize\":\"35\"}'"` 
Is this why solution is not working for me? when I do a console.log, it shows me string in format, you have stated. Please help me out if possible.

Comment: @newbietocoding Yes, that isn't a valid JSON string. You need to reformat it. See my edit

Comment: @newbietocoding Actually my changes didn't save. I've saved them now, see my edits